# subscript ell in R annotate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use ell as subscript in my plot, but I still get l instead of ell. Here is the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-7, 21)), aes(x)) +
 stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 5, sd = 3))+
 stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = 9, sd = 3)) + 
 theme_void() + theme(legend.position="none") +
 annotate("text", x = 5, y = 0.15,size = 5, label = 
  as.character(expression(paste("f(E | X"["\u2113"], ")" ))) , parse = T) +
 annotate("text", x = 9, y = 0.15,size = 5, label = 
  as.character(expression(paste("f(E | X"[h], ")" ))) , parse = T)
```

Comment: I can reproduce error (I'm getting `ell`) `ggplot2_2.2.1`

Comment: I've also ggplot2_2.2.1 but I get l not the fancy ell

Comment: I correctly get `|`. I am using R 3.4.2 with ggplot2_2.2.1.

Comment: the question isn't about getting | but ell(fancy l, "\u2113") as a subscript

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 5 years old, but I just encountered the same problem and while I have not figured out your specific case, using

```
element_text("\u2113")
```

has worked for me.